# Do you change from cycling clothes when out and about

Tags: touring, clothes

OK, fairly new to cycling, and looking at getting some cycling clothes. Question is do you change into different clothes if, for example you go in for a meal during a days cycling?

Comment: If out for a long ride and need a meal, then no. But one has to choose a fairly informal place to eat - preferably with outdoor tables. Such places are common where I live. YMMV

Comment: Pick a casual place.  You can get cycling shorts that look like regular shorts.  If you want to dress it up put on a collar shirt.

Comment: @Blam something like [this](http://assets.esquire.co.uk/images/uploads/fourbythree/_540_43/Brompton-World-Championship-Races-You-Can-Win-43.jpg)?

Comment: How far are you riding and on what terrain?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're considering as cycling clothes, but it's generally not considered to be a good idea to sit around in a sweaty chamois for long periods of time.  I always heard it caused saddle sores, it's certainly uncomfortable.

Answer (score 4):

Just a matter of priorities, really. If I'm riding out to a meal, then I'll wear clothing appropriate for the meal, and choose my bike accordingly.

However if I'm out on a day's ride, I'll dress appropriate for the ride and a spare set of clothes just represents bulk. Do I really want to carry that extra weight? No way.

Third scenario, if I am away on a multi-day cycling trip, I will wear cycling gear for the day's riding, but will have a shirt and some trousers for the evening. These have to be as light as possible, as again they represent bulk in my pannier. I suppose I could get away with eating in the hotel in my lycra, it's just possibly a bit whiffy for other diners!

Answer (score 3):

Being of the female persuasion, I sometimes bring a maxi dress in a lightweight fabric that I can throw on over cycling gear. I bike in Keen sandals, which are good enough for casual restaurants.

I've found that many restaurants near a bike trail are used to it, even appreciate bikers as customers. (Shout-out to the Grumpy Troll in Mt. Horeb, Wisconsin!)